# iPhone XS Max 16.2 - Sometimes I receive WhatsApp calls/messages while mobile data is disabled

Tags: ios, permission, whatsapp.app

I keep getting WhatsApp and Facebook messenger calls and messages despite disabling the mobile data on my iPhone for the apps.
I have no WiFi connection.

What could be the reason? These permissions management are just a farce aren’t they? Those apps can access everything regardless of not permitting them.

Comment: Try disabling WiFi assist.  Is your WiFi on, but just no networks available?  Do you have the same problem if you explicitly  disable WiFi?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148138/489896

Comment: @Allan yes my WiFi is off